# Citrix Receiver NotSupportedException

Tags: server, citrix, receiver, notsupportedexception, xenapp

Citrix Receiver seemed to randomly stop working.  When attempting to open a published desktop, I get the following error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3573O.png]

I have uninstalled (using receiver cleanup utility), re-installed, installed previous versions, added the URL to IE's trusted sites list all to no avail.

*I am using windows 8.1...have attempted the app from the app store as well*

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to logon with another Windows account.

Some cache files of Citrix Receiver are stored in AppData folder of user's profile. So reinstalling might not solve an issue.

Or you can try to delete user cache directories:

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\ICAClient
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Citrix\Receiver
```